# How to addClass() and removeClass() on button:focus by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with my code.

I would like to build a button menu where it will be focused when it clicks firstly and it will not when it is clicked the second time.

This is my code :

```
    <style>
       .mybutton:focus{
         background-color:red;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#menu-button").click(function(){
            if($(this).is(":focus")){
                    $(this).removeClass("focus");
            }
            else
            $(this).addclass("focus");
        });
    });
    </script>
```

It doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: `"#menu-button"` not appear at `html` ?

Comment: #menu-button is the id of the button,
<button type="button" id="menu-button">
sorry for not writing that

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ? What is `.mybutton` ? Is expected result to toggle both pseudo selector `:focus` and `class`  `.focus` ?

Comment: <button type="button" id="menu-button" class="mybutton">
sorry

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your if statement, use `.toggleClass("focus")`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menu-button").click(function(){         
        $(this).toggleClass("focus");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct method name is `addClass`, not `addclass`. Try Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menu-button").click(function(){
        if ($(this).is(":focus")) {
            $(this).removeClass("focus");
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("focus");
        }
    });
});
```